# Method not allowed in REST PUT

Tags: rest, iis

I know this has already been asked. I am in a crisis here.

I cannot make a PUT method to work. Just REST services. iis 7 windows 7 64 bits.

I get Method not allowed, and not a single hint. I am using a .svc file.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: What precisely is the error message? What code are you trying to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been downvoted, but if you check around, many people has been troubled by this.

So, things I learned:

- ENABLE Trace Failed Requests!!! I was relunctant, and I should have done it before. Might have saved a full day and night, because I am the kind of guy that get obsessive with technical problems.
- PUT methods can not be tested via url in a browser!!!!

I finally solved it by uninstalling WebDAV, thanks to Failed Trace!! I had already tried that, but I was sometimes checking with Chrome Rest Extension,  and sometimes via URL in a Browser. Apparently, when I firt tried WebDAV uninstall, I never checked with Chrome Rest...
I know, I know, a was until yerterday a complete newbie. Now I am just a newbie.

I ended up writing my own code to consume the services to have full control.

For you guys having the same problem, please enable tracing failed request. Then, in the XML output, look for:

405

Close to that you will found the bastard causing it. In my case, it was webDAV.
Rememeber to use a tool that actually sends a real PUT verb, like rest Chrome Extension, or your own app. NOT URL in a Web Browser.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

There could be many reasons why this is happening, I would recommend that you add the below to your web.config (just before the  is closed), so that you can get some diagnostics information on what your WCF webservice is doing :

```
 <system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData= "c:\temp\webservicelog.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
```

Also, are you placing PUT in the method operation contract like below :

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "DoWork")]
```

Comment: Thats the problem. Many reasons!